# one button stretched, others are original size

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to use the `btn-group` of the `bootstrap` package to display set of buttons in a single group/row. In my case group consists of:

- 1 image at the start
- 1 button in the middle
- 1 more image at the end

Is it possible to stretch button in the middle to full size (stretch to maximum 100% size) **while keeping original size of two buttons on the sides**?

I have done several attempts, and currently I am using second one (see **fiddle**).
The problem is that i have images instead of icons so their size can vary... I can not just set the fixed size for all first and last elements of group in every scenario..

Another way to do it would be to use `jQuery` to set proper sizes of buttons after document is already initialized. Is there a proper `CSS` solution maybe?

**fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/kufzamc6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for JQuery you can do this with `Flexbox`. Here is [`Demo with img`](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/512/)

```css
.btn-group.mytest {
  display: flex;
}

.middletest {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="btn-group mytest" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
  </label>

  <label class="btn btn-sm btn-default active middletest">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" checked>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
    Object Tip A
  </label>

  <label class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: works even better than I expected :) Minimum amount of lines!

Comment: I have just noticed that in `IE` there is an issue that the label which has `flex:1` - has no width if some part of the group is hidden by overflow.. no such issue in `Chrome` though. But for now - that will do :)

Comment: What version of `IE`?

Comment: using version 11. Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ec2t2e9d/ It's like overflow is not working in `IE`.. strange.. On my `localhost` apache server the results are a bit different (overflow working) but in either case `IE` seems to be breaking something..

Comment: does it work OK in your `IE`? Maybe mine doesn't have some updates :) No, still the same

Comment: okay I found solution... for `IE` you have to use `flex: 1 0 auto;` instead of `flex: 1;` :) I found answer here: http://degradingdisgracefully.com/ie11-ie10-flexbox-overflow-bug/ I didn't read the post so maybe author's problem was a bit different though.. but his solution worked just fine